# Centos Bind remote query issue

Tags: centos, bind, query

I have trouble with remote access to dns server

Ip address of server is 199.175.53.128

I run this command from server

```
host cloudauth.me. 199.175.53.128
```

this command returns

```
Using domain server:
Name: 199.175.53.128
Address: 199.175.53.128#53
Aliases:

cloudauth.me has address 199.175.53.128
```

But when i run this command from remote (e.g. from my computer)

```
host cloudauth.me. 199.175.53.128
```

This error occures

```
Using domain server:
Name: 199.175.53.128
Address: 199.175.53.128#53
Aliases:

Host cloudauth.me.bsu.az not found: 5(REFUSED)
```

Bind server configurations

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

acl "trusted" {
199.175.53.128;
10.153.154.0/24;
localhost;
localnets;
};


key "rndc-key" {
    algorithm hmac-md5;
    secret "i1zJyYwAZUOJPF6VQ2JhYw==";
};


// we assume our server has the IP 192.168.254.207 serving the 192.168.254.0/24 subnet
controls {
        inet 127.0.0.1 allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndckey"; };
        inet 199.175.53.128 allow { 199.175.53.128; } keys { "rndckey"; };
};

options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 199.175.53.128; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { 127.0.0.1; 199.175.53.128; };
    match-clients      { any; };
        match-destinations { any; };
    recursion yes;
allow-query { any; };
allow-recursion { any; };
allow-query-cache { any; };

    query-source address * port 53;


    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    default-key "rndc-key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

zone "ns1.cloudauth.me" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/cloudauth.me.hosts";
    };

zone "ns2.cloudauth.me" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/cloudauth.me.hosts";
    };

zone "cloudauth.me" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/cloudauth.me.hosts";
    };
zone "test" {
    type master;
    file "/var/named/test.hosts";
    };
```

And /var/named/cloudauth.me.hosts

```
$ttl 38400

@                 IN SOA          ns1.cloudauth.me. ns2.cloudauth.me. (
            1360150327
            10800
            3600
            604800
            38400 )

cloudauth.me.      86000   IN      A       199.175.53.128

cloudauth.me.      86000   IN      NS      ns1.cloudauth.me.

cloudauth.me.      86000   IN      NS      ns2.cloudauth.me.

ns1  86000   IN      A       199.175.53.128

ns2  86000   IN      A       199.175.53.128

www      86000   IN      A       199.175.53.128
```

What is wrong ? what must i  do for working of dns server from remote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `allow-query` from any and, to avoid abuse of your server, set `recursion no` in your conf file.